write and read binary data in python
I am trying to write an array of data a binary file with the intention of later accessing said file to locate data. I looked around online finding multiple methods to save data from using df.to_pickle, struct.pack, np.to_bytes(). Now comes the part of reading it. I found other posts requesting reading but so far none have aided in retrieving the data. I am under the impression it might have to do with how I compress the data.
data format
      0      1      2     3     .      .      .    n
0   
1  -0.111 
2   0.84   0.1
3   0.25   0.6   -0.2
.
.
.
n

This is a comparison dataset so at the cross of variables, it is 1. Due to memory allocation constraints and data size, it resulted in generating a data table like this in a text file. Storing in memory was not possible as n can be very very big.
To convert to binary, I read each line in the text, convert the values to the correct format and then use numpy.array.tobytes()
save_path = Path(save_loc)
save_data = save_path.open()
with load_data_path.open() as data_chunk:
    for idx, data in enumerate(data_chunk,0):
        if idx == 0:
           save_data.write(b"\n")
           continue
        dlist = data.strip("\n").split(",")
        d_array = [np.float64(x) for x in dlist]
        save_data.write(d_array.tobytes())
save_data.close()

for reading the data, I attempted to use np.frombuffer and struct.unpack but both resulted in errors. In addition from my understanding, the reading would pull all the data into memory which would not work for my data. I opted to open the binary using path, locating the line and reading it directly. Here is the code
find_line = 7984
load_data = Path(data_loc)
with load_data.open("rb") as data_chunk:
     for idx, data in enumerate(data_chunk,0):
         if idx < find_line:
              continue
         else:
              my_line = np.frombuffer(data, "f", idx)
              break

this however results in an error
ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size

edit:
Upon further investigation, I have found three issues in my code. 1 is that my formating was incorrect when using frombuffer. As I encodes as np.float64, calling "f" tries to return a float32.
the second is that I assumed writing the binary file would maintain the writing blocks (with an "\n" as the delimiter for each block) but this is not the case as when I tried to look at my first few lines, they each had 2000 bits when they should only have ~16.
finally, it appears that "\n" is being added somewhere into the process as when loading further down the list, I find more "\n" values that break up the bytes. I should have ~60,000 bytes to be loaded in but a line breaks only returns ~2500 bytes

Consider if your data contains a b'\n' (newline byte).

Ideally, make a [mcve] with small sample input data (say, 10x10) that illustrates the problem.

thanks for the reply, I have figured out a chunk of my problem. I updated the question to reflect it. though I might delete as the question has since morphed. the problem is due to the lack of delimiters in my binary file. and the "\n" does not make a good delimiter. I read that by appending the length in front, I can delimit when a new line appears but I am unsure how to integrate this in my table setup

Are the lines variable size or are they fixed?  Then just use .read(n) where n is the number of bytes in a line (float64 size times number of columns).  If the data format is n by n, write n and a newline as the very first line of the file, use .readline() to read it, then .read(n) for all the lines after.

the lines are variable in size but I know the length. For instance line 0 has no data, line 7500 has 7500 np.float64 values.

So read "row number times 8 (size of float64)" as a fixed number of bytes with .read(n).  No delimiter needed.

thanks a bunch, I see what I can do now.

In a binary file, the b'\n' character (byte value 0x0A) can occur in the binary float data, so delimiters aren't required or desired.
Per clarifying comments in the OP's question, each line (numbered from 0) contains "line#" columns.  A numpy.float64 is 8 bytes long. Read "line# * 8" bytes and keep track of the line number.
Use csv.reader to simplify reading the input.
input.csv (example, note intentional blank first line):

-4.0
-3.0,-2.875
-2.0,-1.875,-1.75
-1.0,-0.875,-0.75,-0.625
0.0,0.125,0.25,0.375,0.5
1.0,1.125,1.25,1.375,1.5,1.625
2.0,2.125,2.25,2.375,2.5,2.625,2.75
3.0,3.125,3.25,3.375,3.5,3.625,3.75,3.875
4.0,4.125,4.25,4.375,4.5,4.625,4.75,4.875,5.0

Code (Python 3.12):
import csv
import numpy as np

# Convert data to binary file.
# Row 0 writes nothing.
# Row 1 writes one 8-byte float.
# Row 2 writes two 8-byte floats.
# etc.
with (
    open('input.csv', newline='') as fin,
    open('output.bin', 'wb') as fout
):
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        data = np.array(row, dtype=np.float64)
        fout.write(data.tobytes())

# Find and display specific line in the file as float64 values.
find_line = 5  # int(input(line))  # ask for line
line = 0
row = b''      # Initialize to handle row 0 case

with open('output.bin', 'rb') as fin:
    # line 0 is empty so skip read
    # Read until nothing is read after that.
    while line==0 or (row := fin.read(8 * line)):  # float64 size(8) times number of columns in line
        if line < find_line:
            line += 1
        else:
            my_line = np.frombuffer(row, dtype=np.float64)
            print(my_line)
            break
    else:
        print('not found')

Output:
[0.    0.125 0.25  0.375 0.5  ]

